# Why "foreach" loop returns Key while "indexer" returns Value from a NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, foreach, namevaluecollection

I have a NameValueCollection which contain several items. When I try to retrieve a value from that collection, it returns me the **Key** from the collection

```
NameValueCollection col= new NameValueCollection();
    col.Add("Item1", "Foo");
    col.Add("Item2", "Bar");
    col.Add("Item3", "Pooh");
    col.Add("Item4", "Car");
    foreach (string val in col) 
    {
       if (val == "Item3") //val contains the Key from the collection
          { break; }
    }
```

While on the other hand, if I try to retrieve the value from indexer in a for loop, then it returns me the **Value** from the collection

```
for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++) 
{
    string val = col[i];
    if (val == "Pooh") //val contains the 'Value' from the NameValueCollection
    {
       break;
    }
}
```

Why there are different type of results for these different type of loops?

Comment: For doesn't return "value". Indexer accepts both index and key. Enumerator iterates through keys and it's reasonable because with key you can also get value...

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with the loop, it is simply the operations that you're performing on the data structure in that loop, as is clearly defined in the documentation for that type.

Comment: this article is clearly from a young bloke learning to code. shame on all of you that came and down voted it; he was courteous and clear... just a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a collection of associated String keys and String values
>   that can be accessed either with the key or with the index.

ForEach accesses the String key
col[val] would access the value via the key

In the second you are accessing the value via the index

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the C# source code, we can see why this happens:

**[Indexer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/namevaluecollection.cs,80d0316befb424f2)**

```
/// <devdoc>
/// <para>Represents the entry at the specified index of the <see cref='System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'/>.</para>
/// </devdoc>
public String this[int index] {
    get 
    {
        return Get(index);
    }
}
```

The indexer, what you access using the i variable in the loop, returns the value at that index.

**[Enumerator](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/nameobjectcollectionbase.cs,c45b5df2db0ed458)**

```
/// <devdoc>
/// <para>Returns an enumerator that can iterate through the <see cref='System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase'/>.</para>
/// </devdoc>
public virtual IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
    return new NameObjectKeysEnumerator(this);
}
```

The enumerator, what you get when using the `foreach` statement, gives you the list of keys of the `NameValueCollection`.